# install the same debian packages on another system

Tags: debian, package-management, export

How do I export a list of installed Debian packages on a system, and then install those same packages on a new system?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To backup:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections > /tmp/dpkglist.txt
```

To Restore:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < /tmp/dpkglist.txt
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Also see this question for additional options and info: [Ubuntu, how to setup a new machine like an existing one](https://serverfault.com/questions/737/ubuntu-how-to-setup-a-new-machine-like-an-existing-one)

I have the above running in a daily cronjob that checks the dpgklist into SVN as part of our server inventory. This will allow you to keep a reasonable accurate inventory of installed packages across your servers and its easy to do a quick side-by-side diff to see if a server is missing a particular package.

Comment: I get this error message for each input line:

```dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line ...```

Comment: this way doesnt work since few ubuntu versions

Answer (score 13):

`aptitude` also satisfies this usecase, and it preserves information about "automatically installed" packages that other methods do not. Run the following on the reference machine:

```
aptitude search -F '%p' '~i!~M' > package_list
```

Copy `package_list` to the other machine and run

```
xargs aptitude --schedule-only install < package_list; aptitude install;
```

Comment: Just a minor note.
According to the aptitude reference manual, the "package" field is "expandable" by default, so
`aptitude search -F '%p' '~i!~M' > package_list`
should also work fine.

Comment: Regarding package backup: see plug for `deborphan` @ http://bogdan.org.ua/2013/10/18/saving-restoring-list-of-packages-installed-on-debian-using-aptitude-deborphan.html

Comment: `[insert your own linebreaks, since http://serverfault.com/editing-help#linebreaks lies]`

Regarding package restore: this will need to be done as root, no? If so,<br/>

The `xargs` in your restore commandline=

    xargs aptitude --schedule-only install < package_list; aptitude install;

makes me want to know,<br/>

1. Why does `aptitude` need the `xargs`? `dpkg --set-selections` doesn't.<br/>

2. Presuming `aptitude` *does* need the `xargs`, where to put one or more `sudo`s in your restore commandline? Or otherwise get root for running that line, presuming that's necessary.

Comment: Presumably, `aptitude` does not accept a list of packages on stdin but only on the command-line.  The `xargs` command will do that, even calling the command multiple times if there are more than some limit (500 by default?) of values.  `sudo` would need to be specified before `xargs` which will then run `aptitude` as the same user.  And again before `aptitude` after the semicolon (`;`).

Answer (score 0):

That's a good idea, and you might also set up one server with [apt-proxy](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/406) if you make a habit of this.

Comment: After playing around with several proxies for apt, I ended up deciding on apt-cacher-ng. apt-cacher-ng is very simple to setup and from several accounts it seems to be more robust than the original apt-proxy. Each person has their own favourite though.

http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/

Comment: My vote is for approx, it's the only one that isn't some kind of insane.

Comment: Interesting... I've not actually tried any of the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

faultyservers answer worked for me only after running a different command as per http://rayslinux.blogspot.de/2012/10/ubuntu-1210-dpkg-warning-package-not-in.html

`sudo apt-get install dselect
sudo dselect access
sudo dselect update`

Before that running

`sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade`

only returned

> [...]
>   dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 302: xfonts-utils
>   dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
>   is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method
>   pi@FHEM-new:/tmp $ sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I was trying to install the same packages from my old Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)) on my new Raspberry (Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)).

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, `dpkg` needs available packages to be in its "avail" database for **`dpkg --set-selections`** to work.

Example sequence:

1. (On other system) **`dpkg --get-selections > installed.dselect`**
2. **`sudo apt update`**
3. **`apt-cache dumpavail | sudo dpkg --merge-avail`**
4. **`sudo dpkg --set-selections < installed.dselect`**
5. **`sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade`**

The third command populates dpkg's "avail" database.  It's important to run this *before* setting the selections of which additional packages to install.

This reqires dpkg v1.17.7 and later.  See [Q: Why does ''dpkg --set-selections'' not record selections for unknown packages?](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_Why_does_.27.27dpkg_--set-selections.27.27_not_record_selections_for_unknown_packages.3F) on the Debian wiki for more details.